# Is it possible to create a post from an NextGen Gallery image?

Tags: custom-field, plugin-nextgen-gallery

I have uploaded many pictures, and I would like to create a new post for each of them with a specific category named `photos` and a custom field `url` with the url of the image.

Is that possible ?

I imagine a button `Create Post` in the NextGen interface next to `View / Edit / Delete` links

Do you know if there are a plugin or something like that ?